# Moving Wi-Fi driver module to another OS

Tags: raspbian, wifi, driver, osmc

I have a Wi-Fi adapter (the chip is Realtek [RTL8192EU](http://www.realtek.com/products/productsView.aspx?Langid=1&PNid=21&PFid=48&Level=5&Conn=4)) which I use with my Raspberry Pi 2. I first tried using it with Raspbian Jessie (based on [Debian 8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debian#Release_timeline)), but the driver was not installed by default and although I have read a lot of posts about this issue, but they did not work for me. At that moment I gave up.

Later I discovered that on OSMC the right driver for my chip is installed by default, and I have been using OSMC for a while now. My [Raspberry Pi Zero](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raspberry_Pi#Specifications) arrived yesterday, and I would now like to use the Zero with the Wi-Fi adapter on Raspbian.

Would it be easy to find out which driver my adapter uses on OSMC and then move that module to Raspbian and how would I find the right module?

This is the output of [lsmod](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lsmod):

```
Module                  Size  Used by
cfg80211              542368  0
rfkill                 22502  2 cfg80211
uinput                  9818  1
8192eu               1149759  0
sg                     23797  0
uas                    15902  0
joydev                  9713  0
evdev                  11627  4
lirc_rpi                9315  3
bcm2835_thermal         2844  0
bcm2835_gpiomem         4026  0
bcm2835_wdt             4081  0
lirc_dev               11576  1 lirc_rpi
uio_pdrv_genirq         3885  0
rc_core                25681  1 lirc_dev
uio                    10364  1 uio_pdrv_genirq
fuse                  106878  1
ipv6                  441571  48
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oke, it has been a while and I completely forgot about this question, but this is how it turned out: the WiFi dongle ended up in the junk-drawer... After some effort I was able to find the right sources for the dongle and tried to compile them on Raspbian. That is the moment I found out why it worked on OSMC and not on Raspbian. OSMC is build with a much older kernel then Raspbian is and it used a lot of functions that where deprecated and removed in the newer Raspbian kernel. I have run into this sort of problem before and was able to replace the deprecated functions with a simple search and replace, but that wasn't an option here and modifying the driver for the newer kernel was going to take a LOT of work, so I bought another WiFi dongle for my Rpi and "archived" :) this one.